# Mount krb5.configMap and hadoop.configMap on executor pods : Spark on Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I am using Spark on Kubernetes to run Spark jobs. The spark version is 3.0.1. The requirement is that the cluster may need to connect to an external Kerberos enabled Hadoop cluster, or any other Kerberos enabled data source such as Kafka.

As per the documentation ([Spark on K8S Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/running-on-kubernetes.html#:%7E:text=kubernetes.kerberos.krb5.-,path,-(none))) I am providing krb5 configs by setting spark.kubernetes.kerberos.krb5.configMapName and Hadoop configuration by setting spark.kubernetes.hadoop.configMapName properties with the appropriate config maps.

The issue is, the config maps are being mounted on the Driver pod only and are not being mounted on the executor pods. While connecting to the Kerberos-enabled data sources such as Kafka or Hive On JDBC, individual executors need to have Kerberos tickets. Since this ( krb5 ) configmaps are not being mounted on the executor pods, it becomes difficult to obtain the ticket.

Below is what I see when I describe driver pod v/s what I see when I describe executor pod.

Driver Pod:

```
Environment:
 SPARK_USER:                 root
 SPARK_APPLICATION_ID:       spark-5c1dd6f967e2734jsduis92365428724
 SPARK_DRIVER_BIND_ADDRESS:   (v1:status.podIP)
 HADOOP_CONF_DIR:            /opt/hadoop/conf
 SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS:           /var/data/spark-e3435455-55b0-4506-82be-b5e4545351fec
 SPARK_CONF_DIR:             /opt/spark/conf
Mounts:
 /etc/krb5.conf from krb5-file (rw,path="krb5.conf")
 /mnt/secrets/kerberos-keytab from kerberos-keytab (rw)
 /opt/hadoop/conf from hadoop-properties (rw)
 /opt/spark/conf from spark-conf-volume (rw)
Volumes:
  hadoop-properties:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      spark-hadoop-config
    Optional:  false
  krb5-file:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      hadoop-kerberos-config
    Optional:  false
  some other volumes....
```

Executor Pod:

```
Environment:
      SPARK_USER:             root
      SPARK_DRIVER_URL:       spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@driver-service.svc:7078
      SPARK_EXECUTOR_CORES:   2
      SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY:  8g
      SPARK_APPLICATION_ID:   spark-5c1dd6f967e2734jsduis92365428724
      SPARK_CONF_DIR:         /opt/spark/conf
      SPARK_EXECUTOR_ID:      2
      SPARK_EXECUTOR_POD_IP:   (v1:status.podIP)
Mounts:
      /var/data/spark-e3435455-55b0-4506-82be-b5e4545351fec from spark-local-dir-1 (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from namespace-sa-token-xgwxp (ro)
Volumes:
  spark-local-dir-1:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
 namespace-sa-token-xgwxp:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  namespace-sa-token-xgwxp
    Optional:    false
```

We can see that the krb5 and hadoop configmaps are not being mounted on the executor pods. Is this the expected behavior or am I missing something?

I am stuck with this issue, and any help on this would be helpful.

Thanks,
Swathi Desai

Comment: Kerberos was designed a long time ago, and is a very bad fit for distributed systems. Hadoop solves that hiatus with _delegation token_ ==> Spark driver uses Kerberos to obtain a list of token for select Hadoop services, then pushes these to the executors. For long-running jobs the driver also manages token renewal.

Comment: I don't know how Spark connectors for Kafka handle Kerberos. AFAIK it's not supported for JDBC at all -- build the whole framework by yourself, if necessary...

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter On Spark on K8S shouldn't these configurations be mounted on executors as well, and shouldn't executors try to obtain the ticket during bootstrap?

Comment: Spark is supposed to be somewhat agnostic to the underlying execution framework. No reason to completely f*ck up the existing codebase to fit the current hype i.e. Kubernetes, IMHO. Plus - it's the driver that negociates/renews the token, not Kubernetes (nor Vault nor whatever contraption you use for static/dynamic secrets management)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be bugged, doesn't work for me as well.

Source: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/33257#issuecomment-882289114

What does work for me is mounting the configmaps myself to `$SPARK_HOME/conf` on the driver, Spark then creates a configmap that consists of the files inside `$SPARK_HOME/conf` and mounts it to the `$SPARK_HOME/conf` of the executor pods.

Use `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` and `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` with `-Djava.security.krb5.conf` to pass the correct path to the krb5.conf file and `spark.hadoop.home.dir` to set the hadoop home directory.

The thing that I dislike is that it creates a new configmap per spark job, and also you might not have a way to mount those configmaps to your driver depending on how you run your spark job, you could try using pod template files https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/running-on-kubernetes.html#pod-template.